# How to change background color of a psuedo selector on scroll down

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have been struggling to find a way to select pseudo elements in JS to change the color of it when a user scroll.

To be more specific I am working on a fixed navigation bar which changes background color and text color on scroll. 
But I need to change the the pseudo selector to a different color when it is scrolled.
This is what i use for all of the other elements ( i know its very redundant, but for now its just prototyping until i get a handle on JS and DOM manipulations).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var removeColor = $('.navigation__item');
var posColor = removeColor.position();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= posColor.top & windowpos >=1) {
        removeColor.insertRule('header__navigation--change');
    } else {
        removeColor.removeRemove('header__navigation--change');
    }
});
});
```

CSS:

```
nav.header__navigation a{
color:#fff;
font-size:1em;
text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
display:block;
padding: 0.6em 0;
letter-spacing: 0.08em;
@include for-desktop-up {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:0.7em;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight:300;
};
}
nav.header__navigation li::after {
    @include for-desktop-up {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #fff;
      transition: width .3s;
      margin-top: -15px;
    };
}
nav.header__navigation--change li::after {
    @include for-desktop-up {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #000;
      transition: width .3s;
      margin-top: -15px;
    };
}
nav.header__navigation a:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
}
nav.header__navigation li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: consider using CSS variable

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942898/how-to-rotate-input-type-range-thumb-in-javascript/49942972#49942972

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could you please give me an example? I was reading: [Css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) but since im new to variables and JS i dont quite get it yet. Thanks.

Comment: I already did ;) check the link i shared for an example using CSS variable and pseud classes

Comment: Ah I see, didnt notice they where connected haha. I still have a hard time to see how this can be implemented though:( Guess i just have to read more about it. Thanks for the push in the right direction, and yea i can see how this is very effective use of code.